# How to write Matlab's dot operators in mathematical expressions?

Tags: notation, matrices

Matlab has a set of dot operators, such as .*, ./, .^. Each of these operators consists of a dot and a normal algebraic operator. They perform element-wise algebraic operations on a matrix. For example, consider the following codes

```
A = [1 2 3; 3 2 1];
x = [1 2 4];

B = A.^2
y = 1./x
```

The result is

```
B =

     1     4     9
     9     4     1

y =

     1.0000    0.5000    0.2500
```

I find these dot operators very convenient. My question is, how to write these dot operators in mathematical expressions? (By mathematical expressions, I mean the expressions used in proofs.)

EDIT -
One obvious way is to define the result matrix element-wise. But is there a way to write this result in a more compact manner?

Comment: The Matlab notation was heavily influenced by APL. APL was intended originally as a compact notation for doing mathematics. As a result, for the kinds of operations operations you appear to be talking about, the usual mathematical notation is typically going to be longer than the Matlab code. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_%28programming_language%29)

But bear in mind, you're free to write $y=1/x$ to mean $y_k=1/x_k$ in a proof, as long as you state your intentions clearly and unambiguously.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I followed the link to APL; it is interesting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your matrix $B$ is the Hadamard product of $A$ and $A$ which uses the notation $B = A \circ A$. However I don't know of any others, particularly for expressing $y$.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Hadamard_product

Answer (score 1):

I might write those as $B_{ij} = (A_{ij})^2$ and $y_k = \frac{1}{x_k}$ (where i, j and k range over the rows and columns of A and the elements of x respectively).  Of course, I'm sure other ways exist too.

Comment: Oh thanks for your response! But are there more compact ways to write these facts?